# status labeling for transactions

Tags: sql-server

So we have a transaction table and I'm trying to append the most recent status to transactions but I'm stumped as to how to deal with multiple status changes within a day. Here is an example account

```
CREATE TABLE Status
([account] bigint, [TransactionDate] datetime, [TransactionTime] int, [Code] varchar(3), [TransactionSequence] int, [OldStatus] int, [NewStatus] int, [TransactionAmount] money);

INSERT INTO Status
([account], [TransactionDate], [TransactionTime], [Code], [TransactionSequence], [OldStatus], [NewStatus], [TransactionAmount])
VALUES
(8246, '2015-11-02 00:00:00', 6615, 'RT', 3, -1, -1, -808.21),
(8246, '2015-11-02 00:00:00', 6615, 'ITD', 2, 00047, 00082, NULL),
(8246, '2015-11-02 00:00:00', 6615, 'PT', 1, -1, -1, 808.21),
(8246, '2015-11-02 00:00:00', 6616, 'RT', 3, -1, -1, -808.21),
(8246, '2015-11-02 00:00:00', 6616, 'ITR', 2, 00047, 03058, NULL),
(8246, '2015-11-02 00:00:00', 6616, 'PT', 1, -1, -1, 808.21),
(8246, '2015-11-05 00:00:00', 9600, 'E56', 2, -1, -1, '-121.94');
```

Here is how the data should look

```
account     TransactionDate TransactionTime Code    TransactionSequence     CurrentStatus   TransactionAmount
8246        2015-11-02      6615             RT        3                    00047            -808.21
8246        2015-11-02      6615             ITD       2                    00082            NULL
8246        2015-11-02      6615             PT        1                    00082            808.21
8246        2015-11-02      6616             RT        3                    00082           -808.21
8246        2015-11-02      6616             ITR       2                    03058            NULL
8246        2015-11-02      6616             PT        1                    03058            808.21
8246        2015-11-05      9600             E56       2                    03058           -121.94
```

Basically it needs to be sorted by transaction date (asc), then time(asc), then sequence(descending) - I've done this already.

I'm struggling to create the new CurrentStatus column which would be based off the OldStatus/NewStatus columns. If it is before a status change row happens (a row where New/Old are not -1) , it uses the first OldStatus. After the first status change happens, all rows following it (including itself) should be that status change's NewStatus. In this case rows 2-4 should be 82, and row 6-8 should be 3058. (This data is abbreviated as there can be as many as 50+ transactions in a day so it has to work for more than just 2 rows after a status change)

Comment: " if there are no non -1 values" ? ugly and confusing double negative. Do you mean " if there are only -1 values"? ;)

Comment: how do you receive the data? one row at a time? or a batch of rows as with the data values you show in your example? I believe the trick here is in how you would do an INSERT.

Comment: unfortunately the data is already in the table. it comes in as an overnight batch. i'm just doing reporting on the data. it would be lovely to have code that corrects it as it comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to use OldStatus if the previous sorted NewStatus doesn't equal -1. If it does equal -1 then use the current rows NewStatus.  Here is one way to achieve this.

```
;with cteRowNum as(
select 
    *,
    Rank() OVER (order by TransactionDate asc, TransactionTime asc, TransactionSequence desc) as RowNumber
from Status)

select
    c.account,
    c.TransactionDate,
    c.TransactionTime,
    c.Code,
    c.TransactionSequence,
    c.OldStatus,
    c.NewStatus,
    c.TransactionAmount,
    c.RowNumber,
    case 
        when c.NewStatus = -1  and c.RowNumber = 1 then lead(c.oldstatus) over(order by c.RowNumber)
        when c.NewStatus = -1  then Lag(c.NewStatus,c.RowNumber - (select max(RowNumber) from cteRowNum where RowNumber < c.RowNumber and NewStatus <> -1)) over (order by c.RowNumber)
        else c.NewStatus
    end as CurrentStatus
from
    cteRowNum c
```

Comment: if you look at the example, i actually want to replace all the -1 with the most recent status. the only exception is the transactions that happen before a status change happens (then its the first old status value when it changes)

Comment: i ran both sets of  code and all im seeing is a new current status column that = new status (and the row number)

Comment: how do you determine the most recent status?  your grouping logic doesn't seem to fit anything

Comment: based on the row number you generated the most recent status is the largest row number with a new status <> -1. i played around with the lag/lead functions and i can get the row after a status change to correct but everything after that has to look at the lag of CURRENT status to pick up the correct status.

Comment: Then shouldn't the third and 4th row in your results be 47 and not 82?

Comment: no because new status always overrides old status. the only time old status gets used is **before** any status changes happen in this case thats only 1st row. 47 is the old status in row 2. (thats the status change row) so that row and everything after that (until the next status change row) is that status (2-4) then when the new status change happens (5) that row and all the others (5-7) are of that new status (3058)

Comment: Ok... i updated the answer. I use rank here instead of RowNumber() to seperate the dates which I'm sure you will run into.

Comment: i looked into the new version but the extra offset only works for one more row then it breaks. for this example i cut out the bulk of the data and its not unusual to have 50+ transactions on an account on a single day with multiple status changes. i need some way for the offset to be dynamic so i dont need 50 case statements to look back to the last status change.